# How to parse HTML added by code behind using vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net

How to parse `HTML` added by code behind using `vb.net` code ?

the code to create `HTML`

```
Dim str As String = 
     "(<input id='hdnConfrimValue' type='hidden' runat='server' />" &
      "<script>" &
          "$('.test').live('click',function(){" &
             " var answer = confirm('Do you really want to go here ?');" &
              "if (answer)" &
                 " $('#hdnConfrimValue').val('Ok');" &
              "else $('#hdnConfrimValue').val('No'); " &
          "});</script>"
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(control, GetType(Button), "sas", str, False)
```

how to get `hdnConfirmValue` using `vb.net` code?

Comment: (backticks for code formatting don't work in the question title, unfortunately)

Comment: You cannot register a server controls as `String`. Add it to the `Page's` [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.aspx) somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're adding the hidden field like that, but you should just be able to access it like this from the code behind:

```
Dim confirmStr as String = hdnConfrimValue.Value
```

That is, if it were added to the page normally.

Is there a reason why you're adding it dynamically like that?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that you could always use the trusty old FindControl:

```
Dim confirmStr As String = _
TryCast(form1.FindControl("hdnConfrimValue"), HtmlInputHidden).Value
```

Where form1 is your form name - assuming your JS gets injected inside the form and not in the header. And you can probably leave out runat="server" on your hidden field...

Comment: Is it possible to store the value in Cookie, and use it later ?